# How to print a set of PDF Files in using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Hi I want to print(using printer) list of PDF files using nodejs. But not able to find any proper way. I found one JavaScript library called print.js(http://printjs.crabbly.com)
But with that also I m not able to call it in loop.

Is there anything I can do for this.

```
var pdflist = [a.pdf,b.pdf] //(this is my PDF list)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ghostscript** command line tools from your node app by forking a child process to execute the commands and loop thru your pdfs.

```
// OS : windows 64bits (for other OSs : linux, macosx ...etc; it's almost the same thing)
//assuming here that pdf is the path string to your pdf file
//printer name : Apple LaserWriter II NT 
pdflist.foreach( function (pdf,index){
   require("child_process").exec('gswin64c.exe ... -sOutputFile="%printer%Apple LaserWriter II NT" ' + pdf,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                  console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                  return;
            }
            console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      }
   );
});
```